# My Sign in buttons are turning black after 5 second of launching the application in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, button, launch

these are the codes used in SplashScreenActivity

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      companion object{
        private const val LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 7171
    }

    private lateinit var provider: List<AuthUI.IdpConfig>
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth:FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var listener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        delaySplashScreen();
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        if (firebaseAuth != null && listener != null) firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener{listener}
        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun delaySplashScreen(){
        Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
            }
    }
```

I have checked  the theme or styling applied to the buttons. and also tried to perform by making some changes still i got the same result.